# Why am I getting a weird results from my scaleImage method?

Tags: java, android, scale, image-scaling

I'm trying to scale an image in relation to the width/height. Here is my method:

```
private byte[] scaleImage(Bitmap image) {
  byte[] image = new byte[]{};
  int width= image.getWidth();
  int height = image.getHeight();
  int wh = width / height ;
  int hw = height / width ;
  int newHeight, newWidth;
    if (width> 250 || height> 250) {
        if (width> height) { //landscape-mode
            newHeight= 250;
            newWidth = Math.round((int)(long)(250 * wh));
            Bitmap sizeChanged = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight, true);
           int bytes = størrelseEndret.getByteCount(); 
           ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); 
           sizeChanged.copyPixelsFromBuffer(bb); 
           image = bb.array();
       } else { //portrait-mode
            newWidth = 250;
            newHeight = Math.round((int)(long)(250 * hw));

            ...same 
           }
         }
           return image;
      }
```

After that, I wrote some codes to convert the image from `Bitmap`to `byte[] array`, but after a `Debug` I noticed that I'm getting really weird values. For example:
`width = 640`, `height = 480`, but `wh = 1`, `hw = 0`, `newHeight = 200` and `newWidth = 200?`! I simply don't understand why? what am I doing wrong? Any help or hints is very appreciate. Thanks, Carl

Comment: Well, `wh` is `width`/`height`, and all the values are integers - what would you *expect* `wh` to be? (If you were expecting 1.3333, then think about what "integer" means...)

Comment: you get a point. But it is wise to convert to double?

Comment: Well if you want to perform non-integer arithmetic, yes. Alternatively, you could use `newWidth = (250 * width) / height` for example - get rid of `wh` and `hw` entirely.

Comment: Um, where do you get that from? It's not clear whether or not you understand the problem at this point... basically I would suggest replacing `newWidth = Math.round((int)(long)(250 * wh));` with `newWidth = (250 * width) / height;` and the equivalent for `newHeight` in the second block.

Comment: ok..i understand what you mean. I am not sure but maybe it is better with Ìnteger`, i will not chane to `double`?

Comment: My suggestions there don't require any `double` arithmetic - basically because I'm doing the multiplication before the division.

Comment: Thanks. Little help (i mixed little bit!) and on the road again! (How to mark your solution)

Comment: Will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a problem of integer arithmetic, basically - you're performing a division to get a scaling factor, but as an integer - so for something like 640x480, the scaling factors would be 1 and 0, because 640/480 is 1, and 480/640 is 0.

Instead of handling this as `(x1/y1)*y2`, you can change it to `(x1*y2)/y1` so that you perform the division *afterwards*. So long as you don't overflow the integer limit in the multiplication (unlikely here) it should be fine. So I'd rewrite your code as:

```
private byte[] scaleImage(Bitmap image) {
  byte[] image = new byte[]{};
  int width = image.getWidth();
  int height = image.getHeight();
  int newHeight, newWidth;
  if (width > 250 || height > 250) {
    if (width > height) { //landscape-mode
      newHeight = 250;
      newWidth = (newHeight * width) / height;
    } else {
      newWidth = 250;
      newHeight = (newWidth * height) / width;
    }
  } else {
    // Whatever you want to do here
  }
  // Now use newWidth and newHeight
}
```

(I would definitely separate the "calculating `newWidth` and `newHeight`" from "performing the scaling" if possible, to avoid repeated code.)

Comment: Clear and comprehensive. Thanks again.